# How to validate JSON objects using Newton JSON and C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am new to Tests in Visual Studio , normally I always used proper test tool in order to validate the json file and its data

I am stuck how to validate JSON objects , data inside in the JSON File

through following code I am Reading the JSON file , further i would like to validate the JSON objects

here is my readJSON method which reads the file but now I would like to either check if it contains  any given specific value let say I would like to check if it contains the "Details" and its value "XYZG" or not

I tried to convert JSON into ToString() and then user .count method but it gives me the value 0 in output so I removed that ToString() block from the code

JSON Data

```
{
    "Details":"XYZG",
    "City":"Tokyo",
    "Id":"ATOOO",
    "Name":"Johny"
}
```

read json method

```
public string ReadMyJsonFile(String FilePath)
        {
            string storeValue = "";
            using (StreamReader readerobject = new StreamReader(FilePath))
            {
                string jsonString = readerobject.ReadToEnd();

            }
            return storeValue;

        }
```

TestMethod

```
public async TaskTest()
        {
          var json = ReadMyJsonFile(@"FilePath/Test.json");
            var testobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);
            Console.WriteLine(testobject);

            try
            {
                if (testobject.SelectTokens("$..Id").Any(t => t.Value<string>() == "$..Id"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n \n value exist");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("error keyword");
            }

        }
```

´´´

I am kinda stuck with the validation part of my json data

Comment: What exactly  is `0` value here?

Comment: on a output console when i tried to use ToString.Count it prints 0

Comment: There is no `Count` in the code you posted .... Please show the code you are talking about, or talk about the code you are showing...

Comment: sorry my bad i tried count() method but it gives me 0 as an output so I removed.

Comment: And you are searching for tokens with literally value `"$Id"`. There is no such tken in your JSON so you won't find any ...

Comment: @Bilawal on what?

Comment: for example when i am  replacing "$Id" with "City" still its not showing that object "City" exist in my json file , am i missing some validation trick ?

Comment: You are using JSON path. Are you aware what `$..Id` means in JSON path? How would this expression find a property named `City`?

Comment: And again, either show the code you are talking about or talk about the code you are showing. Nobody knows what you replaced where and which actions led to what results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you better print a json string, not a JObject

```
     try
    {
        var json = ReadMyJsonFile(@"FilePath/Test.json");

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("json file exists \n");
            Console.WriteLine(json);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("json file not exists \n");
            return;
        }

        var testObject = JObject.Parse(json);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)testObject["Id"]))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n Id value exists");
            Console.WriteLine((string)testObject["Id"]);
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("\n Id value doesnt exist");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("error "+ex.Message);
    }
```